# Convert dataframe from datetime['ns'] to datetime['us']

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a column of my pandas dataframe from datetime['ns'] to datetime['us'].

I've tried using `astype` but the column type doesn't seem to change. I need the type of the column itself to update due to some downstream libraries checking for a specific column type.

```
>> data[column].dtype.name
'datetime64[ns]'
>> data[column] = data[column].astype('datetime64[us]')
>> data[column].dtype.name
'datetime64[ns]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce, the *behaviour* you describe, in [`1.5.3`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v1.5.3).

So, you're most likely using a similar version or at least older than ([`2.0.0`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v2.0.0)). Why ?

[Backwards incompatible API changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-api-changes) :

> In past versions, when constructing a Series or DataFrame and passing
> a `datetime64` or `timedelta64` dtype with unsupported resolution
> **(i.e. anything other than "ns")**, pandas would **silently** replace the
> given dtype with its **nanosecond analogue**.

To get your cast work, you need to update your pandas' version :

```
pip install pandas==2.0.0

# or pip install -U pandas # latest
```

Minimal Reproducible Example :

```
import pandas as pd # >= 2.0.0

data = pd.DataFrame({"dt": pd.date_range("20240101", freq="T", periods=3)})

data["dt"].dtype.name # 'datetime64[ns]'

data["dt"].astype("datetime64[us]").dtype.name # 'datetime64[us]' <<
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas internally represents datetime data in nanoseconds (`datetime64[ns]`) by default. When you try to convert it to microseconds (datetime64[us]), pandas don't change the internal representation of the data, hence the `dtype` still shows as `datetime64[ns]`. If you want to output the data with microseconds precision, you can try the following:

```
data['datetime_column'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```